# Get Multiple COUNTS Multiple JOINS from Schedule table

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have 3 tables:

`test_member`, `test_member_addon` & `test_schedule`.

- A member can only have 1 test_member.Type (test_schedule.prod_type =
  1)
- A member can have multiple test_member_addon.Type
  (test_schedule.prod_type = 2)

I am trying to return Distinct Counts for each DISTINCT test_schedule.mem_ID, test_schedule.Prod_Code in the Schedule that is Future Dated and `schedule`.`status` = 1.

Schedules should have the correct amount of payments eg. 52 for 'Weekly'. If `Correct` & `Actual` do not match, I then can fix.

**MY QUERY: Does not return correct values for `Amount`, `Period`, `Correct` or `Actual`.**

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.mem_ID,
CASE WHEN s.prod_type = 1 THEN ROUND(m.next_amount,2) ELSE ROUND(ma.next_amount,2) END AS Amount, 
CASE WHEN s.prod_type = 1 THEN m.Period ELSE ma.Period END AS Period,
CASE WHEN s.prod_type = 1 THEN 
(
CASE WHEN m.Period = 'Weekly' THEN 52 
WHEN m.Period = 'Fortnightly' THEN 27 END
)
ELSE
(
CASE WHEN ma.Period = 'Weekly' THEN 52 
WHEN ma.Period = 'Fortnightly' THEN 27 END 
)
END AS Correct,
COUNT(*) AS Actual, 
s.prod_code, 
s.prod_type
FROM `test_schedule` s, `test_member` m, `test_member_addon` ma 
WHERE m.ID = s.mem_ID AND ma.mem_ID = m.ID 
AND s.status = 1 
GROUP BY s.prod_code, s.mem_ID 
ORDER BY s.mem_ID, s.prod_type;
```

**DB Build Scripts:**

```
CREATE TABLE `test_member` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `next_amount` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `period` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prod_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `test_member` (`ID`, `next_amount`, `period`, `prod_code`) VALUES
('1','50','Weekly',11),
('2','35','Fortnightly',11);

CREATE TABLE `test_member_addon` (
  `mem_addon_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mem_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `next_amount` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `period` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prod_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mem_addon_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `test_member_addon` (`mem_addon_ID`, `mem_ID`, `next_amount`, `period`, `prod_code`) VALUES
('1','1','25.55','Weekly',22),
('2','1','15','Fortnightly',33);

CREATE TABLE `test_schedule` (
  `sched_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mem_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prod_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prod_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `amount` float NOT NULL,
  `sched_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sched_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `test_schedule` (`sched_ID`, `mem_ID`, `prod_code`, `prod_type`, `status`, `amount`, `sched_date`) VALUES
('1','1','11','1','1','50','2014-03-21'),
('2','1','11','1','1','50','2014-03-28'),
('3','1','11','1','1','50','2014-04-04'),
('4','1','11','1','1','50','2014-04-11'),
('5','1','11','1','1','50','2014-04-18'),
('6','1','22','2','1','25.55','2014-03-21'),
('7','1','22','2','1','25.55','2014-03-28'),
('8','1','22','2','1','25.55','2014-04-04'),
('9','1','22','2','1','25.55','2014-04-11'),
('10','1','22','2','1','25.55','2014-04-18'),
('11','1','22','2','1','25.55','2014-04-25'),
('12','1','22','2','1','25.55','2014-05-02'),
('13','1','22','2','1','25.55','2014-05-09'),
('14','1','33','2','1','15','2014-03-21'),
('15','1','33','2','1','15','2014-04-04'),
('16','1','33','2','1','15','2014-04-18'),
('17','1','33','2','1','15','2014-05-02'),
('18','1','33','2','1','15','2014-05-16'),
('19','1','33','2','1','15','2014-05-30'),
('20','1','33','2','1','15','2014-06-13'),
('21','1','33','2','1','15','2014-06-27');

Current Return Data:
mem_ID |    Amount   |    Period    | Correct  |  Actual  |prod_code | prod_type
1      |    50.00    |    Weekly    |    52    |    10    |    11    |    1
1      |    25.55    |    Weekly    |    52    |    16    |    22    |    2
1      |    25.55    |    Weekly    |    52    |    16    |    33    |    2 

Correct Data:
mem_ID |    Amount   |    Period    | Correct  |  Actual  |prod_code | prod_type
1      |    50.00    |    Weekly    |    52    |    5     |    11    |    1
1      |    25.55    |    Weekly    |    52    |    8     |    22    |    2
1      |    15       | Fortnightly  |    27    |    8     |    33    |    2
```

Comment: distinct counts for test_schedule.mem_id... what do you want counted? the number of distinct rows in the table for each member?
test_schedule.Prod_Code... do you just want the distinct prod_codes per member here?

Comment: Hi John. I am attempting to return: the number of rows per mem_ID,prod_code (Actual should return 5 for prod_code 11, 8 for 22 & 8 for 33)  + the period + the period count (Correct for Fortnightly would be 27, Weekly 52) + The ie. in the example I have given

Comment: Sorry added by mistake. In the example I have given the return data Doubles all the 'Actual' counts and Returns incorrect values for Amount, Period (all Weekly) and Correct (all 52).

Comment: I have added the current return data and the expected return data.

Comment: How can you tell from your current table schema which period is used in `test_schedule`? Right now you don't provide for this. The only workaround is to use amount to join appropriately but this is wrong by all means. Also don't use float for monetary values. Instead use precise data types:  either decimal (e.g decimal(10, 2) or decimal(10, 3)) or int (and store money values in cents).

Comment: Sorry, this is a dummy build: Original tables are massive.
I have changed the type fields to prod_code so they can now link to the schedule.
Appreciate your feedback on the Float, and am aware, this is part of a legacy application that has thousands of fields like this so just maintaining consistency with code base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way

```
SELECT mem_id, prod_code, prod_type, period, 
       ROUND(MAX(amount), 2) amount, 
       CASE WHEN period = 'Weekly' THEN  52 ELSE 27 END correct,      
       COUNT(*) actual
  FROM
(
  SELECT s.*, m.period
    FROM test_schedule s JOIN test_member m
      ON s.mem_id = m.id 
     AND s.prod_code = m.prod_code
     AND s.prod_type = 1
   WHERE s.status = 1 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT s.*, a.period
    FROM test_schedule s JOIN test_member_addon a 
      ON s.mem_id = a.mem_id 
     AND s.prod_code = a.prod_code
     AND s.prod_type = 2
   WHERE s.status = 1 
) q
 GROUP BY mem_id, prod_code, prod_type, period
```

Output:

```
| MEM_ID | PROD_CODE | PROD_TYPE |      PERIOD | AMOUNT | CORRECT | ACTUAL |
|--------|-----------|-----------|-------------|--------|---------|--------|
|      1 |        11 |         1 |      Weekly |     50 |      52 |      5 |
|      1 |        22 |         2 |      Weekly |  25.55 |      52 |      8 |
|      1 |        33 |         2 | Fortnightly |     15 |      27 |      8 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33b8e/3)** demo

Comment: Fantastic thank you peterm.

I have been searching for this answer for many months. I will sit down tomorrow and study, so I can understand the process.

Very big thank you. If I award you points, how do I do this?

Comment: You're quite welcome :) You can **[upvote and accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** the answer if it is what you were looking for.